# How to pass inner typedef which is "int X::*" as template function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

In this code, I want to pass the address of `x.y` as the template parameter `typename Name::Type leValue`.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct X {
   X() : y(123) {}
   const int y;
};

template<typename Name, typename Name::Type leValue>
void print() { cout << *leValue << endl; }

struct Foo {
   typedef int X::* Type;
};


int main() {
    X x;
    print<Foo, &x.y>();  // What is the right syntax here?
}
```

However, with gcc 4.7.2, I get the following errors:

> source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   source.cpp:22:5: error: parse error in template argument list
>   source.cpp:22:22: error: no matching function for call to 'print()'
>   source.cpp:22:22: note: candidate is:
>   source.cpp:11:6: note: template void print()
>   source.cpp:11:6: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   source.cpp:22:22: error: template argument 2 is invalid

If I instead change the typedef to `typedef int Type;`, and the print call to `print<Foo, 3>();`, then it works. I tried several things by looking at the error messages, but could not get the syntax right. I have also searched here, and found some useful posts dealing with template classes, but none dealing with template functions. I tried using those answers but it did not help.

Could you please help me with this syntax, or explain to me what I should try doing next to fix this?

Comment: `x.y` is just a `const int`.

Comment: @Xeo I tried it, it didn't work.
`error: could not convert template argument '&X::y' to 'Foo::Type {aka int X::*}'`

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Well, `&X::y` is a `const int X::*`, and `Foo::Type` is `int X::*`.  The two types are not compatible.

Comment: @aschepler Oh right, I don't see why I missed that. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct X {
   X() : y(123) {}
   const int y;
};

template<typename Name, typename Type, Type Name::*Member>
void print(Type& obj) { cout << obj.*Member << endl; }

int main() {
    X x;
    print<X, const int, &X::y>(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this problem. However, the inner typedef is the essential part. I am working with a client's code, and the code I pasted in the question is a anonymised and simplified version of the same.

Comment: Note that when `Name` is a template parameter, if all you want is the nested type, not a particular pointer-to-member, you can just use `typedef Name::Type` as a type in the definition. You don't need another template argument.

Answer (score 1):

The address of `x.y` is unknown in compile time. You can take a pointer to the member `y` as template argument, however, you have to pass the address of the object instance in run-time.

Comment: I see what you mean. The code I shared is an anonymised and simplified version of client's code. Maybe I did not describe it correctly. Let me think through it once more.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you change it to an int because your allowed to pass const ints as template parameters.  Templates will not let you pass values as arguments because they need to be resolved at compile time.